# VSC: Vuetify intellisenseclass name

Tags: vuetify.js, vscode-extensions

I'm looking for a VSC extension to get class names of [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/), for example: `h0`, `d-flex`, `w-100`, and so on. I tried to find another Stackoverflow post but can't get it.

Vuetify class name docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/

#### Is there some VSC extension for intellisense Vuetify class names?

Answer (score 0):

This VSC has the auto-complete class names feature: [vuetify-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vuetifyjs.vuetify-vscode)

> Attention: They use [camel case](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/CamelCase) in the dropdown selection. See the image:
>
> [image]